# In Bemidbar 2.14 , it says רעואל is the father of Eliasaph. Isn't the father of Eliasaph דעואל?

Tags: names, bamidbar-parsha

This is the only instance I know of that רעואל is known as the father of Eliasaph ,
דעואל is known as the father of Eliasaph in bemidbar 1.14, and 3 other places, the resh and the Dalet are very similar, is that the reason ?

Comment: Worth noting that Reish and Dhaled might not be that different a sound (I don't mean an American "R" sound or a modern Israel "R" sound, but a classical Reish. Think like an Arabic or Spanish R sound.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, based on my limited knowledge of Teimani Hebrew and Arabic, I think the phonemes are fairly distant. I would opine that the above is caused by a sofer's error, as both Palæo-Hebrew and Ashurit have fairly confusable forms, if the scribe's vision isn't great.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Similar written forms for similar sounds may not be a coincidence.

Comment: Is it possible that "De'u'el" was there intentionally to distinguish him from Yitro, who was also know as "Re'u'el"?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I don't think a Spanish rolled R and a Dhaleth Rafeh (like in English: THe) are that different at all. In the latter the tongue is just a bit further forward.

Comment: @DoubleAA, as soon as I read your response, I went over the sounds and I maintain my perception that they are distant enought to avoid confusion. Furthermore, they're in different parts of the mouth (source: making said phonemes with my mouth) the [R] based phonemes are distinctly farther back than the [Ð]

Comment: @noach Think of the middle consonant in English "ladder". Isn't that an alveolar tap? That's not unlike a short alveolar trill, nor clearly is it far from a D, as the letter chosen is indeed D.

Comment: @noach see too shulchan arukh oc 61:7 http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.61.7? that one should be careful in shema that the dalet not sound like a reish.

Comment: @DoubleAA, note however the clear distinction between ladder and lather. The phonemes are sufficiently distinct in the latter as far as I can hear and דֿ is closer to lather. Also, I'm prettys sure that the issue with reading ד as a ר in שמע is that אחד (one) becomes אחר (other)

Comment: I'm not saying they are the same. They are similar. Much more similar than most american english r speakers first assume. Similar sounds can lead to confusion in spelling and also similar written forms for similar sounds may not be a coincidence. Too many americans think r and d are completely different and hence it has to just be a typo because of similar written forms, when really there's more to think about.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Certainly Acher/Echadh is why the ShA bothers to remind you here to be so careful. But it still indicates that there is a tendency to sometimes blur them.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Since the daleth in דעואל always has a dagesh, it would be pronounced as an alveolar stop, very close to an alveolar trill/flap.  However one pronounces /ð/ is irrelevant for this example.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I only started arguing the point of the דֿ after you mentioned it. I don't think that דּ is really near ר phonetically, though.

Comment: @magicker72 Ping ^^^ (though I note it's not clear BGDKPT rules were always the same everywhere and I think being open minded about /dh/ is prudent here)

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of possibilities as shown by [Rabbi Buchwald](http://rabbibuchwald.njop.org/2016/06/05/bamidbar-5776-2016/). Rav Hirsch, besides citing the Ramban refers to his own commentary on Vayishlach 36:1 which explains the concept of multiple names for individuals.

Note that [THE BIBLE "CODES": A TEXTUAL PERSPECTIVE](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~jtigay/codetext.html)

> 14. The two versions are laid out side by side, with differences highlighted, in Abba Bendavid, Makbilot BaMikra' (Parallels in the
>       Bible) (Jerusalem: Carta, 1972), p. 61-62. Kimhi held that such
>       differences as Dodanim in Gen. 10:4 vs. Rodanim in 1 Chron. 1:7, and
>       Deuel in Num. 1:14 vs. Reuel in 2:14 are due to confusion of similar
>       letters, but he held that the confusion took place in pre-Biblical
>       texts and that the Bible intentionally preserved both forms to show
>       that they referred to the same peoples or persons; there was no
>       confusion in the transmission of the Bible itself (see his comments to
>       Gen. 10:4 and 1 Chron. 1:7, and Uriel Simon, "Ibn Ezra and Kimhi --
>       Two Approaches to the Question of the Accuracy of the Masoretic Text,"
>       Bar Ilan 6 (1968):208-209).

Points out that the Radak mentioned below is not from Bamidbar but is referred to as part of his explanation of this and similar differences. I have not found the actual location in Radak so I do not know (other than the quoted article), where the Radak says this.

I found a reference to Moshe Cassuto, professor of Bible at the Hebrew University, who suggests an alternative answer. He suggests (involving the Dodanim in [Noach 10:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8174#v=4&showrashi=true) and [Divrei Hayamim I 1:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16521#showrashi=true&v=7) that in both Dodanim and Deuel, the names are actually shortened forms of a longer name.

> Once again we have a “daled” and a “resh” interchanged. He suggests
>   that the original name of the people was “Derodanim”, however, they
>   were known better in its shorter form, as both the Dodanim and the
>   Rodanim. So too, Eliasaph's father. His full name was Deru’el. However,
>   he was called by both its shorter forms; sometimes called De’uel and
>   sometimes Re’uel.

[Rabbi Buchwald](http://rabbibuchwald.njop.org/2016/06/05/bamidbar-5776-2016/)

> The commentators raise an issue regarding the leader’s name. In the
>   very next chapter, in Numbers 2:14, when the camp’s setup and
>   structure are described, the prince of the tribe of Gad is identified
>   with a slight change as, אֶלְיָסָף בֶּן רְעוּאֵל, Eliasaph the son of
>   Reuel, not “Deuel.”
>
> Nachmanides suggests that Eliasaph’s father had two names, “Deuel,”
>   which indicates that he knew G-d, and “Reuel,” indicating that he
>   constantly imagined G-d in his heart. Scripture preserved both names
>   in order to convey that both these special qualities were found in
>   Eliasaph’s father.
>
> The Radak says that both names are actually identical. He attributes
>   the change to the fact that both the Hebrew letters, ד–“dalet” and
>   ר–“raysh,” are graphically similar, and are consequently often
>   interchanged. Therefore, some people pronounce the name
>   דְּעוּאֵל–“Deuel” while others pronounce it רְעוּאֵל–“Reuel.” The
>   Torah preserves both names in order to underscore that both names are
>   essentially the same.
>
> Some commentators identify “Reuel” as Jethro, Moses’ father-in-law. 
>   After all, Reuel (Exodus 2:18) was one of Jethro’s seven names. The
>   Baalei Tosafot contend that after he converted, Jethro’s name was
>   formally changed to “Deuel,” indicating that Jethro knew G-d. The
>   problem with this interpretation is that it fails to explain why the
>   child of a convert is listed as the leader of the tribe of Gad.

Note that the child of a (male) convert does not belong to any tribe. However, this may be a reference showing that someone named Reuel could also be called Deuel and not that he was actually the son of Yisro (Reuel - Deuel)

> The Imrei Noam , cited by Pninim ahl HaTorah, says that the change of
>   names comes to teach an important ethical lesson. The Midrash states
>   that the tribe of Dan, who was the firstborn child of Zilpah (Leah’s
>   handmaiden), was given a great honor and was designated to lead an
>   entire דֶּגֶל–degel (banner), that included the tribes of Asher and
>   Naphtali. Gad, who was the first born child of Bilhah (Rachel’s
>   handmaiden), after all, could have easily protested why Dan was given
>   the honor of leading a banner of three tribes and not Gad. Therefore,
>   because Eliasaph was prepared to concede and forego the deserved
>   honor, and did not complain, his father’s name was changed to “Reuel,”
>   which means, רֵעַ אֵ־ל–“Ray’ah Kayl,” a friend of G-d, just like
>   Moses. One who avoids disputes, and is willing to forego a truly
>   deserved honor, is considered to be a true friend of G-d.
>   Additionally, although the exact place of Moses’ burial is not known,
>   he is buried in the territory of Gad, on the east bank of the Jordan.

Comment: That Radak would need an actual source considering there is no Radak on Bamidbar and he doesn't write this in any of the other pesukim with the name Reuel for which we do have his commentary. Also, I would have translated that Ramban slightly differently.

Comment: @user6591 I will add the quote from Rav Hirsch when I get the time saying exactly how Rav Hirsch refers to it.

Comment: @user6591 I found a reference that cites Radak but says that the comments are in Bereishis and Divrei Hayamim. The quote does not say where the Radak is from. I will add the pointer to the post. `(see his [Radak] comments to Gen. 10:4 and 1 Chron. 1:7, and Uriel Simon, "Ibn Ezra and Kimhi -- Two Approaches to the Question of the Accuracy of the Masoretic Text," Bar Ilan 6 (1968):208-209).`

Comment: I used my concordance and checked his pirushim in bereishis and divrei hayamim. Unless I messed up, it wasn't in those places. For the record I checked his seffer hasharashim too. Just in case. Nothing there.

Comment: @user6591 Thanks. I will try to find where the reference is from then. Apparently there is a discussion by Radak on the subject, but I have not found the actual citation about it.

Comment: @user6591 I also found a reference to Yechezkel 6:14 about Radak comparing Divlah to Deuel, but I do not have a copy here so cannot look it up to check if it is a valid reference.

Comment: Sabba he does write there that the words are the same but doesn't say the reason was a mixup due to similar form.

Comment: @user6591 it's here https://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_I_Chronicles.1.7.3

Comment: @Double Thank you.